# Why have memory initialization rules changed in .Net 4.5?

Tags: .net, cil, il

Updating some of my code samples for a training I've noticed that some local memory that was previously kept uninitialized by the **CLR** is now being **zeroed**.

Here is a small **CIL** sample that shows the "issue":

```
.assembly Test{}

.assembly extern mscorlib{}

.class S extends [mscorlib]System.ValueType
{
    .field public int32 n;
}

.method static void F()
{
    .locals (int32, valuetype S)

    ldloc 0
    call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)

    ldloca 1
    ldfld int32 S::n
    call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)

    ret
}

.method static void Main()
{
    .entrypoint

    .locals (int32, valuetype S)

    ldloc 0
    call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)

    ldloca 1
    ldfld int32 S::n
    call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)

    call void F()

    ret
}
```

And here are the outputs:

- .Net 2.0 (and I'm almost sure it was the same with .Net 4.0):

  ```
  $ /Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/ilasm.exe Test.il

  Microsoft (R) .NET Framework IL Assembler.  Version 2.0.50727.5420
  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
  Assembling 'Test.il'  to EXE --> 'Test.exe'
  Source file is ANSI

  Assembled global method F
  Assembled global method Main
  Creating PE file

  Emitting classes:
  Class 1:        S

  Emitting fields and methods:
  Global  Methods: 2;
  Class 1 Fields: 1;
  Resolving local member refs: 3 -> 3 defs, 0 refs, 0 unresolved

  Emitting events and properties:
  Global
  Class 1
  Resolving local member refs: 0 -> 0 defs, 0 refs, 0 unresolved
  Writing PE file
  Operation completed successfully
  Test.il(6) : warning -- Non-sealed value class, made sealed

  $ ./Test.exe
  211384
  0
  2157704
  2157328
  ```
- .Net 4.5:

  ```
  $ /Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/ilasm.exe Test.il

  Microsoft (R) .NET Framework IL Assembler.  Version 4.0.30319.17929
  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
  Assembling 'Test.il'  to EXE --> 'Test.exe'
  Source file is ANSI

  Assembled global method F
  Assembled global method Main
  Creating PE file

  Emitting classes:
  Class 1:        S

  Emitting fields and methods:
  Global  Methods: 2;
  Class 1 Fields: 1;
  Resolving local member refs: 3 -> 3 defs, 0 refs, 0 unresolved

  Emitting events and properties:
  Global
  Class 1
  Resolving local member refs: 0 -> 0 defs, 0 refs, 0 unresolved
  Writing PE file
  Operation completed successfully
  Test.il(6) : warning : Non-sealed value class, made sealed

  $ ./Test.exe
  0
  0
  0
  0
  ```

I'm curious about the rationales behind this implementation change.

So any feedback, especially from insiders, or reference to any articles or, better, to a specification, is welcome. :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's almost certainly in the CIL runtime specifications.  Have you looked there?  Having zeroed fields instead of uninitialized ones is almost certainly more preferable than getting random results back.  No need for much rationale there.

Comment: In the ECMA-335 standard I've seen "If init is specified, the variables are initialized to their default values according to their type: reference 
types are initialized to null and value types are zeroed out." but here there is no "init".

Comment: I suspect that Microsoft originally left the decision of initializing variables to the language compilers.  But since folks like you are digging into the actual IL more often, and an IL program is just as valid as a C# program, it does make sense to push the initialization back into the IL.

Comment: Yes, looks like a good rationale. If I'm digging into the CIL layer it's to show the dichotomy between .Net and the languages like C#: some things are possible at the .Net level (like overloading methods based on return types or letting memory uninitialized) but are prohibited by some languages. I guess I'll have to find another illustration but I liked this one as it is quite strong. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is just a coincidence, nothing clears your locals intentionally. Jitter tries to keep your locals in registers, it doesn't even allocate stack space if it is not necessary. Your program is tiny, and when you don't compile it with /32bitpreferred flag, the odds are good that it chooses a register for your local, which hasn't been used before on the current thread, and still has zero value. You can get back your garbage when you:

- compile the code with /32bitpreferred flag. 32 bit code has less registers, so your locals might be stored on the dirty stack or in a dirty register.
- create more fields for your value type, or use more locals, so they will not fit in the register set, or the jitter doesn't choose to store them there.
- do something more in your methods what involves registers

I am not sure why you need to make more effort to find uninitialized values in version 4.5 compared to previous versions. Maybe this is a side effect of some changes in the jitter, but I am just guessing. The point is that you still need the init flag on your locals to ensure they get zero initial value.